# Appearance of the button's edges in mozilla

Tags: button, mozilla, edges

While I open my site via Mozilla firefox, the edges of buttons is not smooth and well-rounded, I don't have this problem via IE10 or chrome, Please check the following screen-shot:

http://www.jomsocial.com/media/kunena/attachments/118027/bdbtn.jpg

**What is wrong?**

Regards

Comment: Please post the relevant code (HTML + CSS), or a link to the site.

Comment: You can find this issue by log in to the following URL:demo.jomsocial.com / Username: demo / Password: demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need the -moz prefix, but I think that the latest Firefox version doesn't need this prefix. Take a look to [this website](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/)

So your CSS rule should be like

```
border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
```

Ps: sorry for my bad English :P